# Modularize Spring Boot 2 App Results in Failing Integration Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-boot-test

I have a larger Spring Boot Application(Nr.1) which comprises of several modules about 20+ (multi module setup).

Inside that I have another Spring Boot Application (Nr.2) which contains several services etc.

```
app-1
  +...
module-jpa
  +-- pom.xml
  +-- src/main/java/jpa/ (JPA Classes; Entities etc.)
module-repos
  +-- pom.xml
  +-- src/main/java/repos/ JPA Repositories; XYZ extends CrudRepository<..>.
module-app
  +-- pom.xml (dependency on module-jpa and module-repos)
  +-- src
       +-- main
             +-- java
                   +-- xyz
                        +-- application
                                +-- SpringBootApp.java
                   +-- services
                        +-- Service1.java
                        +-- Service2.java
  +-- src
       +-- test
             +-- java
                   +-- services
                        +-- Service1IT.java
                        +-- Service2IT.java
             +-- resources
                   +-- application.properties
```

In the above constellation the integration tests are running fine (Service1IT and Service2IT).

Now I have refactored `module-app` into two separate modules `module-app` and `module-app-cli` cause I wanted to reuse `module-app`. The result looks like the following:

```
module-app
  +-- pom.xml (dependency on module-jpa and module-repos)
  +-- src
       +-- main
             +-- java
                   +-- services
                        +-- Service1.java
                        +-- Service2.java
  +-- src
       +-- test
             +-- java
                   +-- services
                        +-- Service1IT.java
                        +-- Service2IT.java
             +-- resources
                   +-- application.properties
module-app-cli
  +-- pom.xml (dependency on module-jpa, module-repos, module-app)
  +-- src
       +-- main
             +-- java
                   +-- xyz
                        +-- application
                                +-- SpringBootApp.java
             +-- resources
                   +-- application.properties
```

But now the integration tests for `Service1IT.java` etc. are not working anymore with exceptions like:

```
xyzTest(xyz.abcIT)  Time elapsed: 0.141 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'firstService': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'secondService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name '.........'repos.ABCRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What I don't understand is at the moment that just by separating the `SpringBootApp` into a separate module results in failing integration Tests which are not related to the `SpringBootApp.java` but based on the result it looks they are related? The question is: Can this be solved?

I suppose I oversight something which is not clear to me? Does someone has a suggestions what could cause that behaviour?

Some details:

*Using Spring Boot Version 2.1.3.RELEASE*

If you need more informations please leave a comment.

**Update 1**

I'm just trying other ways to fix the issue. So I have started from the beginning and just removed the main SpringBootApp class from `module-app` and removed also the call to spring-boot-maven-plugin in the pom.xml file and the result is simply:

```
service1IT(services.Service1IT)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'xyzService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
```

Answer (score 1):

So after analysing this in depth I found out that the tests lacking the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation which solved the issue (except from others) but this was the most important one.